# Fetch data from API inside Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am working on a project that is divided into two parts:

- Retrieve a specific page
- Once the ID of this page is extracted,
- Send requests to an API to obtain additional information on this page

For the second point, and to follow Scrapy's asynchronous philosophy, where should such a code be placed? (I hesitate between in the spider or in a pipeline).
Do we have to use different libraries like asyncio & aiohttp to be able to achieve this goal asynchronously? (I love aiohttp so this is not a problem to use it)

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing this to fetch additional information about an item, I'd just yield a request from the parsing method, passing the already scraped information in the `meta` attribute.

You can see an example of this at https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-callback-arguments

This can also be done in a pipeline (either using scrapy's engine API, or a different library, e.g. [treq](https://treq.readthedocs.io/en/release-17.8.0/)).
I do however think that doing it "the normal way" from the spider makes more sense in this instance.

Comment: Is it possible to run queries in parallel as we would with a Promise.all in JavaScript ?

Comment: Scrapy is built using twisted, an async framework, so that's what happens by default.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem (again) and found an elegant solution using [Twisted decorators `t.i.d.inlineCallbacks`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.2.0/api/twisted.internet.defer.inlineCallbacks.html).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import re
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks

from sherlock import utils, items, regex


class PagesSpider(scrapy.spiders.SitemapSpider):
    name = 'pages'
    allowed_domains = ['thing.com']
    sitemap_follow = [r'sitemap_page']

    def __init__(self, site=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PagesSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @inlineCallbacks
    def parse(self, response):
        # things
        request = scrapy.Request("https://google.com")
        response = yield self.crawler.engine.download(request, self) 
        # Twisted execute the request and resume the generator here with the response
        print(response.text)
```